# Popover Component not respecting style properties

Tags: reactjs, components, material-ui, popover

The following snippet is supposed to be a Popover sliding from bottom of viewport but the style properties are ignored by Popover component.

The Popover is positioned at the bottom of the document with the size of its content not 100%.

```
   <Popover
       anchorReference="anchorPosition"
       anchorPosition={{ top: 5000, left: 0 }}
       anchorOrigin={{
           vertical: 'top',
           horizontal: 'center',
       }}
       transformOrigin={{
           vertical: 'top',
           horizontal: 'center',
       }}
       open
       style={{
           width: '100%',
           display: 'flex'
       }}
   >
          Popover content. 
   </Popover>
```

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.54",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  }
```

Any idea?

[image: Popover Position]

Comment: Something is wrong in your code. I see closing Box tag but not opening tag

Comment: I fixed it. There was an extra closing Box tag when editing. But the problem is not related to it.